# Manytomany field custom display objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a site where I can manually add photographers to the Django adminpanel and then upload the images taken by them.

I used the default User system in Django and added a field here that shows this user is a photographer or not :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_photographer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Also, in the model that I need to put the images, I used ManyToMany field for photographers (because these photos may have been taken by several people) :

```py
from registration import User

class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    photographers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

The problem is that when adding a new image to the admin panel, users who are not photographers and the `is_photographer` is False, is also displayed in the Photographers. I want only users who are photographers to be displayed and not normal users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Django formfield**. Django has placed these formfields for different types of fields. To use formfields in ManyToMany relationships, you can use [formfield_for_manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany) in the model admin_class.

Try putting this function in the Photo model admin class in the **admin.py** file of the application where the Photo model is located, and if you don't have a class admin, create one like this:

```py
from .models import Photo
from django.contrib import admin
from registration.models import User


class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(is_photographer=True)
        return super(PhotoAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `admin.py` file do this:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs['queryset'] = Users.objects.filter(is_photographer=True)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to):

```
from django.conf import settings

class Photo(models.Model):
    # …
    photographers = models.ManyToManyField(
        setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        limit_choices_to={'is_photographer': True}
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).